# I Just Can't Understand Node.JS, Any Resources and Tutorials Out There To Help Me Out?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this question has been asked multiple times on this site in one way or another, but even after everything I've looked at I still can't for the life of me work out Node.JS nor how to efficiently use it as well as knowing what it's good for.

I consider myself an advanced JavaScript developer. I'm not just talking about knowing jQuery or Prototype, but rather actually knowing the underlying language quite well which from my understanding is all you really need to learn Node.JS as it is server-side JavaScript after all.

I develop on a Windows machine, but have just installed Virtualbox and an Ubuntu Server ISO to develop Node.JS applications in it. Where do I begin? I know the language, but what now? I can't seem to understand how applications are written in it.

Another question (if I hadn't already asked a million of them) is should I be using a framework for Node.JS like Geddy or Express or should I learn Node.JS and then consider a framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [Node Beginner](http://nodebeginner.org/) to be an excellent starting point.

Comment: Wow, yes. My Google-Fu really failed me this time around. I didn't find this site, in-fact all I could seem to find was incomplete tutorials and fragmented pieces of info. I'm going to study that book from top to bottom. Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 3):

If your time for this project is limited, you should jump right at a framework. If you want a deeper understanding of the tools you are working with, start with a barebones tutorial (which does not make much use of frameworks such as expressjs, backbone). I've also found Node Beginner to be the best starting point, so go with Michael Stum's advice.

Later when you will start using those frameworks, you will be able to understand better what each line actually does.

Comment: I don't have a project I want to use it for with a deadline or anything, I just was curious/wanted to learn something new. Node.JS might not be the defacto in a few years time, but one thing is for sure server-side JavaScript compilation and coding is really going to take off sooner or later, already has.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [official nodejs community wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/community). Also see [Useful Node.js Tools, Tutorials And Resources](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/16/useful-node-js-tools-tutorials-and-resources/)

Answer (score 2):

I really would suggest just looking at the documentation on the nodejs.org site itself...

Overview and video http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/
and the [API Manual](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/) which is not too long and worth a read....

I would suggest that you first start with the basics, and the later go with frameworks and modules of which [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules) should be you starting point